# Are pages in the Help Centre CC BY-SA licenced?

Tags: discussion, help-center, copyright

Are pages in the Help Centre CC BY-SA licenced?

The footer says that the site design and logo is copyrighted to Stack exchange, and that the user contributions are licenced under the CC BY-SA. But I'm not sure if the Help Centre is included in either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Per the [legal page](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> All materials displayed or performed on the Network, including ... text, graphics ... (other than Content posted by Subscriber (“Subscriber Content”)) are the property of Stack Exchange and/or third parties and are protected by United States and international copyright laws.

Comment: Your link is wrong. But thanks, I should've thought to check that page.

Comment: Oops @curious; that's what I get for writing on a mobile. Thanks for the edit.